# XML styling with XSL inside a PHP document

Tags: php, xml, xslt

I'm grabbing some data with PHP from an online database. It spits out XML and the data is displayed inside a .php document. With some fancy CSS I can achieve most of want I need to, but looking at all the extra interesting things you can do with XSL I would much rather use it.

**So I've got XML data inside a .php document that I want to style with xsl.**

My problem comes in how to link the .xsl document with the .php. If I input:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="special.xsl"?>
```

then I receive an error (unexpected string etc.).

I'm a PHP newbie so I am sure there is a way to have the file recognize the xsl sheet, but I have been unable to find any information that is clear to me how to do that. Any info I have discovered (some stuff about DomDocument) is just pieces and I end up not being able to figure out how to make it work.

Looking at similar issues on this topic, I have a hunch that I am going about this all wrong and that I am missing something even easier when pulling the data into the .php document.

Comment: Is there any special reason to not store the document as `.xml`?

Comment: Probably none, other than the fact that I am a complete newb at PHP. I have read of ways to utilize PHP to grab the data and then push it out into a .xml file (versus my current set up where it just adds it to the .php file I am using)... but alas, I am unable to interpret said instructions to get anything working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats because `<?` is interpreted by PHP. Try

```
echo '<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="special.xsl"?>'
```

Comment: This did answer my question, but didn't solve my ultimate problem. It appears that because I am using a .php file the xslt doesn't actually format it. (ie it would need to be a .xml file for it to parse correctly.) This is all based upon little experience, and a whole-sale lack of help from the data controller...